# Using Apex Data Loader to load records into object with master details relationship

Tags: csv, salesforce, apex-code, loader

I need to load data into two objects. I am able to load data into one object using the data loader. The second object has a master-details relationship with the first object so I need to have the unique record id of the records of first object in the CSV file. How can I add those record id's to my CSV file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could download the "master" records after initial upload and perform some mapping similar to (Name -> Id). In Excel this could be achieved with VLOOKUP. Once you have generated new list of "detail" objects, there should be no problem uploading them. The mapping "ID->uploaded records" is also available in the success log file created by  Apex Data Loader.

But the better way is to say loudly "screw the Salesforce ID, I don't need no stinking ID" :)
Think if your "master" has some unique field. It can even be the "ID" from your existing system from which you import to Salesforce. Create this field in Salesforce (if you didn't do it already) and mark it as "External ID". Afterwards you will be able to use this external ID instead of normal Salesforce ID as a way to make the link between source and target. In pseudocode:

with normal Salesforce ID you must

```
INSERT INTO detail_object (Name, SomeValue, master_ID) VALUES ("foo", "bar", [some valid salesforce id])
```

With external IDs you can have it easy and tell salesforce to do all the heavy lifting

```
INSERT INTO detail_object (Name, SomeValue, master_ID) VALUES ("foo", "bar", (SELECT Id from master_object where some_field_marked_as_external_id = "123")
```

Check out the [Data Loader user guide](http://na1.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/salesforce_data_loader.pdf) for quick start and play with external ids if you can (in the free developer edition maybe?). It's easier to use than to describe it.

Comment: Be very careful using Excel to do VLOOKUPs on salesforce IDs as the short Salesforce IDs are case sensitive but Excel VLOOKUPs are case insensitive. Also make sure to set the Range search option to false in the VLOOKUP to avoid it just returning the best match rather than the absolute match. Finally the reference data set used by the VLOOKUP must be sorted and the first column must be the key that is being VLOOKUP'd.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Apex Data loader then you will have to do 3 things:

1: insert the master record(s).  this will give them IDs

2: export those master records again including their IDs, and integrate that into your details data.  A VLOOKUP is most useful for that sort of thing.

Or if there is only one master record, even easier, just copy the ID out of the URL and add it in on every detail record in your spreadsheet.

3: then insert the detail records with the master IDs