# Bulk upload Master-Detail objects input data format in salesforce

Tags: salesforce, bulkinsert, bulk-load

I have 2 custom objects Person and Address. Person is master and Address is the detail. I have defined Address in Person as master detail relationship.

How do i define data in csv for bulk upload (using reference bulk upload java code)? Is there any reference XML files which i can use to see how master detail is defined for bulk upload in Salesforce

Thank you
Sameer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you know how to mapping works then what you need to do is first upload the records for the parent object. You can then obtain the IDs for the parent records, and use a method equivalent to a VLOOKUP to put the ID's into the appropriate lookup (MD) field on the child records before you load them.

Comment: Thanks. Found the same solution @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3317774/using-apex-data-loader-to-load-records-into-object-with-master-details-relations Regards Sameer